# How to speed up PostgreSQL query with sorting on aggregate functions results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
select agg.app_id, sum(downloads) as downloads, sum(revenue) as revenue from (
  SELECT distinct app_id FROM sdk_modules_apps
  WHERE sdk_module_id = 27
) agg inner join revenue_hist_sdk ON revenue_hist_sdk.app_id = agg.app_id
group by agg.app_id
order by app_id asc, revenue desc
limit 30
```

This query takes about 1.5 minutes to execute. The EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers) is this:

```
Limit  (cost=8498544.92..8498544.99 rows=30 width=68) (actual time=32005.449..32136.719 rows=30 loops=1)
"  Buffers: shared hit=6491 read=801721 written=312, temp read=1468232 written=1470609"
  ->  Sort  (cost=8498544.92..8499032.40 rows=194994 width=68) (actual time=32005.448..32005.449 rows=30 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: sdk_modules_apps.app_id, (sum(revenue_hist_sdk.revenue)) DESC"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
"        Buffers: shared hit=2409 read=266228, temp read=494935 written=495735"
        ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=7574427.43..8492785.88 rows=194994 width=68) (actual time=20995.772..31969.342 rows=160329 loops=1)
              Group Key: sdk_modules_apps.app_id
"              Buffers: shared hit=2409 read=266228, temp read=494935 written=495735"
              ->  Gather Merge  (cost=7574427.43..8484986.12 rows=389988 width=68) (actual time=20995.663..31752.532 rows=371741 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 2
                    Workers Launched: 2
"                    Buffers: shared hit=6491 read=801721 written=312, temp read=1468232 written=1470609"
                    ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=7573427.40..8438971.80 rows=194994 width=68) (actual time=20532.363..30555.301 rows=123914 loops=3)
                          Group Key: sdk_modules_apps.app_id
"                          Buffers: shared hit=6491 read=801721 written=312, temp read=1468232 written=1470609"
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=7573427.40..8149761.54 rows=38171380 width=20) (actual time=20532.301..28720.598 rows=16933962 loops=3)
                                Merge Cond: (revenue_hist_sdk.app_id = sdk_modules_apps.app_id)
"                                Buffers: shared hit=6491 read=801721 written=312, temp read=1468232 written=1470609"
                                ->  Sort  (cost=7499645.14..7595073.59 rows=38171380 width=24) (actual time=20428.849..24388.498 rows=30537105 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: revenue_hist_sdk.app_id
                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1025856kB
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1073648kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 948424kB
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=328 read=800986, temp read=1466846 written=1469211"
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on revenue_hist_sdk  (cost=0.00..1183013.80 rows=38171380 width=24) (actual time=0.030..4294.558 rows=30537105 loops=3)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=314 read=800986
                                ->  Unique  (cost=73782.26..75108.27 rows=194994 width=4) (actual time=103.447..181.850 rows=267078 loops=3)
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=6163 read=735 written=312, temp read=1386 written=1398"
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=73782.26..74445.27 rows=265203 width=4) (actual time=103.446..137.035 rows=267078 loops=3)
                                            Sort Key: sdk_modules_apps.app_id
                                            Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3696kB
                                            Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3696kB
                                            Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3696kB
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=6163 read=735 written=312, temp read=1386 written=1398"
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sdk_modules_apps  (cost=3147.76..47560.79 rows=265203 width=4) (actual time=16.269..53.601 rows=267525 loops=3)
                                                  Recheck Cond: (sdk_module_id = 27)
                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=1560
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=6149 read=735 written=312
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sdk_modules_apps_sdk_module_id_index  (cost=0.00..3081.45 rows=265203 width=0) (actual time=16.084..16.084 rows=267525 loops=3)
                                                        Index Cond: (sdk_module_id = 27)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1469 read=735 written=312
Planning Time: 0.131 ms
Execution Time: 32388.741 ms
```

The table revenue_hist_sdk contains 90000000 records, and I need to sort by downloads or revenue in this table with joining to sdk_modules_apps. The number of records from sdk_modules_apps is about 250000. I don't really get how to make it faster. I tried to create different indexes with different sorting, but sometimes It got worse.

The tables schemas:

```
sdk_modules_apps: sdk_module_id, app_id, installed, uninstalled
revenue_hist_sdk: app_id, utc_date, downloads, revenue
```

How to handle query long execution time issues when sorting in large tables?

Comment: I get unique list of app_id from this subquery with sdk_module_id = 27, then I join it with the other table, in which I have things to sum and order by

Comment: Ah, I misread the query. Doing away with the `DISTINCT` and replacing the subquery with an `EXISTS` should be a step in the right direction.

Comment: I forgot to say that this table can have duplicates of app_id, and if I delete distinct, I will get app_id duplicates which will result in incorrect sum() results

Comment: Not if you use an `EXISTS` clause rather than a join like I suggested.

Comment: `SELECT app_id, sum(downloads) as downloads, sum(revenue) as revenue
from revenue_hist_sdk rhs
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM sdk_modules_apps WHERE app_id = rhs.app_id AND sdk_module_id = 27
)
GROUP BY app_id
ORDER BY downloads desc
LIMIT 30;` I tried this method but it takes the same time as my query do

Comment: Could you add. `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for that query to the question?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ci2pB7w5, its for the query with exists used, and I've updated my question with explain for my query.

Comment: That takes only 16 seconds, and it will improve if you increase `work_mem`.

Comment: This query doesn't make sense.  Since app_id is unique on the output (due to it being grouped by) then including it first in the ORDER BY completely determines the order, making the following column useless.

Answer (score 0):

Write the query using `exists`:

```
SELECT app_id, sum(downloads) as downloads, sum(revenue) as revenue
FROM revenue_hist_sdk rhs
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sdk_modules_apps a
              WHERE a.app_id = rhs.app_id AND a.sdk_module_id = 27
             )
GROUP BY app_id
ORDER BY downloads desc
LIMIT 30;
```

Then I would suggest indexes on:  `sdk_modules_apps(app_id, sdk_module_id)` and `revenue_hist_sdk(app_id)`.  The second index could also have `downloads` and `revenue` as additional keys.